# Ubuntu Server 16.10 usb stick installation failed

Tags: server, system-installation

during the installation i get this error message on load debconf preconfiguration  file step:
failed to retrieve the preconfiguration file 
the file needed for preconfiguration could not be retrieved from file://cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed.

Comment: The error suggests a problem with the media you're using, either a bad burn or a corrupted ISO to start with.

Comment: can anyone recommend me an ISO file that works for installation of Ubuntu 16.10 and USB creator that worked for him?

Answer (score 0):

You find all current Ubuntu and Ubuntu family iso files via this link, also Ubuntu Server,

[releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com)

There are files with the name MD5SUMS in each subfolder, where you find the md5sums of the listed iso files, so that you can check that the download was good.

If you are running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or newer, you can use the buitlt-in **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator**, but the versions in previous releases of Ubuntu are problematic. Instead you can use [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) or **Disks** (gnome-disks) to install the iso file to a USB stick or memory card. Disks is also built into standard Ubuntu and several Ubuntu family flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ... Xubuntu).

There are more details at [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Please describe with *details* what happens, if there are still problems.

[... help via comments ...]

After solving problems to create a good boot drive you want help to 'see' and to partition the target drive (the internal drive). I expand the answer because I want to use a picture and it might help other users too, who have similar problems.

The Ubuntu Server iso files contain a 'debian installer' in text mode, and it is not as easy to use as the installer 'ubiquity' in the desktop iso files of standard Ubuntu. So I suggest that you use *gparted* which is a tool with a graphical user interface.

Boot a USB live drive made from an Ubuntu desktop iso file if you have one. If you have not, you can download and try a rather small (230 MiB or 252 MiB) self-extracting image file for Windows (to be installed to a USB pendrive with Win32 Disk Imager).

1. Self-extract to a 1 GB img file.
2. Run [Win32DiskImager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb) to install it into a USB pendrive (or a memory card connected via a USB adapter).

There are more details, where to download the files etc, in the following link. These two similar systems are Debian linux systems with *gparted* (and *dus*),

[Two self-extracting 1 GB images of 9w with guidus](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=13583057#post13583057)

which is also described in previous posts in that tutorial thread in the Ubuntu Forums. Boot this USB live drive and use gparted to select the internal drive and to edit the partition table to get what you want:

[image: dus-in-9w_gparted-showing_persistent-live-Lubuntu]

The following link might help, if you have not used gparted before,

[GrowIt.pdf](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/GrowIt.pdf)

Comment: thanks for detailed instructions i manage to have some progress. i checked the md5sum, got a a match than used win32diskimager instead mkusb, since i am running another windows machine through it i made the USB boot stick .                                                                                  i now get a new error on stage: load installer components from cd. there was a problem reading data from the cd-rom. please make sure it is in the drive. if retrying doesn't work, you should the integrity of your cd-rom. fail to copy file from cd-rom retry?

Comment: which file is it? Ubuntu Server 16.10 *i386* or *amd64*? I can check how it works as cloned in one of my computers.

Comment: Ubuntu Server 16.10 amd64

Comment: I'll test it ...

Comment: I made a basic server. It worked. Have you got a working internet connection? (I'm not sure if it is necessary, but my computer in connected.) Could there be a problem with your target drive, for example some bad block in the memory hardware? - *Did you check 'disk for defects' in the boot menu* (where the first item is 'Install Ubuntu Server'?

Comment: Are you booting from CD or USB or memory card? (I think USB, but want to check to be sure.) I cloned it with dus (the 'next' version of mkusb, but they are both using the old ***dd*** under the hood, and should do the same as Win32 Disk Imager.

Comment: Maybe you unplugged the pendrive before Windows had flushed the buffers to it. Did you unmount it to remove safely?

Comment: i have internet connection, i am using a USB boot, i did the 'check disk for defects' stage, it led to stage: configuring d-i. integrity test failed  the ./pool/main/libw/libwww-perl/libwww-perl_6.15-1_all.deb file failed the md5 checksum verifacation.your cd-rom or this file may have been corrupted.        i checked again the md5sums  and they match.

Comment: I suspect that the cloning was interrupted (or failed for some other reason, for example bad RAM or bad USB pendrive). You could try again with *Win32DiskImager*, or you could download and install *Rufus* and try if it will make a good install drive (that passes the 'check disk for defects'. Or try in another computer (if we suspect the RAM) or with another USB pendrive (if we suspect the flash memory hardware).

Comment: o.k tried to use a different usb stick and had some progress though still need help... on partition disks i get only one choice and it is the usb stick disk. how do i partition to internal disk?

Comment: The best alternative is to use *gparted* with a graphic user interface. Boot a USB boot drive made from an Ubuntu desktop iso file if you have one. If you have not, you can download and try a rather small self-extracting image file (to be installed with Win32 Disk Imager). It is described in the following link. It contains a linux system gparted (and dus), https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=13583057#post13583057 which is also described in previous posts in that tutorial thread in  the Ubuntu Forums.